# IOTA Deposit Still Pending for Five Days

Tags: pending, exchanges, binance

I transferred IOTA to Binance about five days ago but to no avail. I did not use the same address and the transaction is showing both in my history on the wallet as well as on Binance but is stuck as pending on both. My balance is still showing the same amount as before I sent the IOTA so I am not worried it has been stolen due to the repeat address issue. Am I using the wrong node or magnitude? How am I able to successfully transfer my IOTA from the wallet to an exchange?

Answer (score 3):

After five days, there is almost zero chance that it get approved by a new transaction because the tip selection algorithm will select recent transactions. According to an IOTA dev (on slack), if the transaction isn't confirmed in less than one hour it will probably remain "pending" forever (or at least up to the next snapshot because it will be forgotten).

The solution is to reattach the transaction (you can do that with the wallet when you click on the transaction in the "history").
Reattaching a transaction means doing the PoW again on two new transactions: It increases your chance that the tip selection algorithm will select your transaction for validation because it will be "recent".

Regarding security: Reattaching doesn't harm because the re-attached transaction has the exact same signature as the pending one (i.e. it doesn't disclose another portion of your private key).

To improve your chances to have your transcation confirmed, you should also select an healthy node to re-attach your transaction. The list of public nodes and their status/health can be found here: https://iota.dance/nodes (select a node with a low "ping" time).